# trying to match match two consecutive words in a list

Tags: python, chatbot

I'm trying to create a very basic chatbot, and this bit is prooving difficult.  One of the things it uses is the order of words; for instance, 'is that' indicates that there is probably a question while 'that is' indicates information.  So I'm trying to write some code that will look for two words together, but that is not the problem.

As you can see below it sometimes generates an number that is equall to len(user_input), and this returns the word along with the first entry in the list, which is matching up the first and last words of the sentence.  How do I stop this?  They must be consecutive, and this is the problem.

```
user_input = [];
user_input = raw_input('User:')
user_input = user_input.split(' ')

from random import randint
a = randint(0,len(user_input))
print a
b = user_input[a] + user_input[a+1]
```

Comment: Okay well if you don't want it to be equal to the length of user_input then do:  `a = randint(0,len(user_input) - 1)`

Comment: Thanks.  Don't know why I didn't think of that.

Comment: Now it is giving this error - IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Then you need to use `len(user_input) - 2` because you increment `a` when you build `b`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python lists are indexed starting at 0, so if `user_input` has `n` elements, they are indexed at `0, 1, ..., n-1`. If you want to randomly select two consecutive elements, you need the first to be indexed at one of `i = 0, 1, ..., n-2` so the second is at `i+1` and stays within the range of allowed indices. Therefore,

```
import random
user_input = 'this is a test string'.split()
n = len(user_input)
i = random.randint(0, n-2)
words = user_input[i:i+2]
print words

['is', 'a']
```

Note that `random.randint(a,b)` returns a uniformly distributed random integer from a to b *inclusive* (unlike NumPy's equivalent method for some reason), and that the slice `[i:i+2]` returns the elements of `user_input` at `i` and `i+1` (ie *exclusive* of any element at `i+2`).